# click.Path sometimes parsed as bytes instead of pathlib.Path

Tags: python, click

I sometimes have the issue that the `click` package fails to return a `Path` when using the `click.Path` argument, and instead I get a `bytes` object. Here is a typical code sample which will sometimes cause the issue:

```
from pathlib import Path
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('-i', '--input-directory',
              type=click.Path(file_okay=False, dir_okay=True, writable=False, path_type=Path),
              help='Directory that contains all input data files')
@click.option('-o', '--output-file', type=click.File(mode='w'),
              help='Path to output file')
def main(input_directory: Path, output_file: Path):
    # fix an error where the argument is read as bytes instead of Path
    if not isinstance(input_directory, Path):
        input_directory = Path(str(input_directory, 'UTF-8'))
```

I am using `click==7.0.2`. The issue seems to only happen when running the script on VMs in a GCP project. The VMs are using either `python3.8` or `python3.10`, both with the same version of `click`. Note that this only occurs with `click.Path`, i.e. when I need to pass a directory as an argument. Whenever possible I use `click.File`, which works with no issues at all.

What should I be doing differently?

Comment: The behaviour seems to be documented: "Not only will it return either bytes or Unicode depending on what makes more sense, but it will also be able to do some basic checks for you such as existence checks." https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/arguments/#file-path-arguments

Comment: Admittedly "makes more sense" is rather vague.

Comment: Yes I saw that in the documentation too, but it feels like a bit of a cop-out, and I wonder why I should use `path_type=pathlib.Path` if what I get is a string. I wish there was a way to fix the bytes to Unicode conversion from the `click.option` part rather than having to do it manually in the function body.